# Objects in SCP memory location

Tags: java, string

```
String s = new String("test");
```

For the above an object is created for test, but what if I assign a string literal to a string variable without using the `new` keyword, will the memory created for that in SCP considered as an object? If so, how can that happen without the `new` keyword?

```
String s = "test";
```

I mean will `"test"` be considered as an object?

Comment: Sure, "  test ".trim() will return "test" for example. No clue which "scp" you are talking about though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s = "test";
```

Here s will refer to an *interned* String object. This means, that the character sequence "test" will be stored at a central place, and whenever the same literal "test" is used again, the JVM will not create a new String object but use the reference of the cached String.

```
String s1 = new String("test");
```

Both String s, s1 gives you String object, but there is subtle difference between them. When you create String object using new() operator, it always create a new object in heap memory and SCP. On the other hand, if you create object using String literal syntax e.g. "test", it may return an existing object from String pool (a cache of String object in Perm gen space, which is now moved to heap space in recent Java release), if it's already exists. Otherwise it will create a new string object and put in string pool for future re-use, so in this case we have:

```
s1 == s // is false
s1.equals(s) // is true
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But as in `String s1 = new String("test")` the "test" will be an object of String class, in which class will the object "test" be created for `String s = "test"` ?

Comment: now i have update answer according to your question.